# Theme etc/view.xml throws error after upgrading to Magento 2.4.1

Tags: magento2.4.1

Recently I have upgraded the site from Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.1 And my etc/view.xml Throws an error

> app/design/frontend/etc/view.xml" is invalid: Element
> 'aspect_ratio': This element is not expected. Expected is ( background
> ).

```
<image id="product_page_image_large" type="image">
    <transparency>true</transparency>
    <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>true</frame>
    <constrain>true</constrain>
</image>
<image id="product_page_image_medium" type="image">
   <transparency>true</transparency>
    <aspect_ratio>true</aspect_ratio>
    <frame>true</frame>
     <constrain>true</constrain>
</image>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of your view.xml

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please follow this link

As you have not attach your code with this issue it hard to say what going wrong

Take backup and then try changing aspect_ratio to background or just remove it as it is optional and also check if aspect_ratio is set to Boolean or not

Follow this [Link](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-images.html) for more info